# How to use regex beginning marker (^) in a kotlin regex statement

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

How do I check whether a string contains and starts with a given regex in Kotlin?

I was expecting that I could just do:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var text = "test string"
    val regex = Regex.fromLiteral("^test")
    val matches: Boolean = text.contains(regex)
    assert(matches)
}
```

But this does not work. It works as expected without the ^. Even doing `matches` or `find`, or the Regex operators like [containsMatchIn](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html) don't seem to work.

Am I missing something obvious? Perhaps I can't use the beginning boundary, or I shouldn't be using it.

Note: I am aware of [startsWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/starts-with.html) but that doesn't allow me to use a regex. I am wanting to use a regex as my code has more complex strings than just "test string".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *`Regex.fromLiteral("^test")`* results in a `\^test` regex that matches `^test` substring *iterally*. Check [*`Regex.fromLiteral()`*](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/from-literal.html) documenation:

> Returns a literal regex for the specified [literal](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/from-literal.html#kotlin.text.Regex.Companion$fromLiteral(kotlin.String)/literal) string.

You just need to make a regex out of the string literal, use

```
val regex = """^test""".toRegex()
```

See the [Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/VWSO24556).

Comment: Ah, knew I was doing something stupid. Makes perfect sense now. Cheers.